# EJS syntax: generate a HTML file with a function whose argument is a string

Tags: javascript, html, forms, syntax, ejs

I use EJS to generate a HTML file with a form, whose characteristics depend on data given the EJS view. In this form, there must be a radio button with an onclick event that is a function taking two arguments (a number and a string (that is a link)).

The function that has be called by the onclick event is written like that:

```
function exam(i, link) {
// content omitted
}
```

I cannot get the right syntax in EJS to call this function is the proper way. That's what I have now:

```
// the way thearray is generated is omitted
<% for(var i=0; i<thearray.length; i++) { %>          
        <% var link = thearray.link %>

<form>
<input type="radio" id= "<%= "examen_non"+i %>" name="examen" value="non" checked>
<label for = "<%= "examen_non"+i %>" >Non</label>
<input type="radio" id= "<%= "examen_oui"+i %>" name="examen" value= "<%= link %>" onClick= "<%= "exam("+i+", "+link+")" %>" >
<label for = "<%= "examen_oui"+i %>" >Oui</label>
</form>  

<% } %>
```

The HTML it renders is like that (I took the lines regarding the form created for the first i of thearray, that is 0):

```
<form id= "question_examen0" >
<input type="radio" id= "examen_non0" name="examen" value="non" checked>
<label for = "examen_non0" >Non</label>
<input type="radio" id= "examen_oui0" name="examen" value= "http://www.diploweb.com/" onClick= "exam(0, http://www.diploweb.com/)" >
<label for = "examen_oui0" >Oui</label>
</form>
```

But then when I click on this button, the function exam(i, lien) with arguments 0 and "http://www.diploweb.com/" is not called. I guess it is because http://www.diploweb.com/ is not coded as a string in the HTML, but how can I make EJS put it as a string?
In other words, how to code EJS in order to generate this HTML:

```
<form id= "question_examen0" >
<input type="radio" id= "examen_non0" name="examen" value="non" checked>
<label for = "examen_non0" >Non</label>
<input type="radio" id= "examen_oui0" name="examen" value= "http://www.diploweb.com/" onClick= "exam(0, "http://www.diploweb.com/")" >
<label for = "examen_oui0" >Oui</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try single quotes, like this:

```
onClick= "<%- "exam(" + i + ", '" + link + "')" %>"
```

Edit: used `<%-` to stop escaping of single quote.

Comment: I just tried. It generates the following HTML: `onClick= "exam(0, &#39;http://www.diploweb.com&#39;)"` that is the single quotes are converted to &#39; and &#39; in HTML...

Comment: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="<%-"testPush()"%>" > Push </a>`  Why `testPush` not found. I've added `function testPush() {}` in the expressjs js file.

Comment: @Gank Add some more detail and ask this as a separate StackOverflow question and more people will be able to help you.